# urllib2 python EOF Error

Tags: python, httplib2

I started writing a script using python (has to be python) to sync some changes from a local database to a remote one.  It runs every 3 hours.  When I started I ran into the urllib2 bug giving the EOF error.  After some poking around I found the following fix which seemed to get everything up and running:

```
class HTTPSConnection(HTTPConnection):
    "This class allows communication via SSL."
    default_port = HTTPS_PORT

    def __init__(self, host, port=None, key_file=None, cert_file=None,
            strict=None, timeout=socket._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT):
        HTTPConnection.__init__(self, host, port, strict, timeout)
        self.key_file = key_file
        self.cert_file = cert_file

    def connect(self):
        "Connect to a host on a given (SSL) port."
        sock = socket.create_connection((self.host, self.port),
                self.timeout)
        if self._tunnel_host:
            self.sock = sock
            self._tunnel()
        # this is the only line we modified from the httplib.py file
        # we added the ssl_version variable
        self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, self.key_file, self.cert_file, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)

#now we override the one in httplib
httplib.HTTPSConnection = HTTPSConnection
```

Today this started throwing the same error again.  Using python 2.6.  Is there another solution or something I'm missing here?

Comment: please add the complete traceback of the error.

Comment: urlopen error [Errno 8] _ssl.c:480: EOF occurred in violation of protocol

Comment: It's a known bug with urllib2